# Bulk insertion for gremlin cosmosdb java/scala

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, bulkinsert, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I would like to ask if there is anyway to bulk insert data into gremlin cosmos db. I am currently using the gremlin api and it is really slow. I am graph GraphBulkExecutor but unfortunately it only works if you are using C# .Net.

Would appreciate if anyone has any suggestion/alternative for bulk insertion into cosmosdb gremlin.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no options for bulk ingest today. The only thing I can suggest is to use autoscale and, if possible, multiple clients to upload data to Cosmos DB to best saturate the throughput.